# Data entry form responses directly to a template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, data-entry

I have created a data entry form in Google Sheets, and would now like the data to be placed in my templates cells automatically. The user fills out a form, and ideally the answers would fill out the template and execute the calculations automatically. Is this possible?

My key questions are to

1. create a new tab with a template for each new data entry (results in a row in the data tab)
2. place entry-values to the tab to execute the calculations

I can also create many duplicate tabs of the template and place each answer to the specific cell manually, but I don't know how many entries there will be.

I have tried to create a new tab with new entries, but the tab is missing my template. I tried to link answers to specific cells, but did not know how.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions on this site should be specific, meaning only one question per post. Also, it's expected that most questions show what was tried (usually by including a [mcve]). Please [edit] the question to limit it to a single question and show what you have tried.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, you are using Google Forms to collect data and store the responses in a Google Sheet.

If that is correct, the best way to manage that input data adding calculations or other extra fields is to use a different tab.

F.e, if your form is collecting responses in tab "Form A", then you need to

1. Create another tab (let's say "curated A responses")
2. Import the data from "Form A" into the second tab
3. Add more fields, calculations, charts... whatever you need.

The simplest way to perform step 2 y using `='Form A'!A:A` for column A and so on.

You write that into the first column of the second tab and it will populate existing and new values automatically.